# server sends file to clients java

Tags: java

I have a server and multiple clients and i am trying to make the server-thread send a file to the all connected clients at the same time.The weird thing is,sometimes the files are written correctly and sometimes the laptop makes noise and the files are written in the console and no files are created.I don`t do any changes in the code between the trials.Could anyone help me about that? Thanks in advance.Here is the sending server-thread code

```
try
{   
    out.println("AcceptFile,");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fn);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(buffer);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()) ;
    oos.writeObject(buffer);
    oos.flush();
}
catch(Exception c)
{
    System.err.println("exc" + c);
}
```

Here is the Client-thread receiving

```
try
{
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    byte[] buffer = (byte[])ois.readObject();
                    String pic="copy"+studId+".pdf";
                    System.out.println(pic);
                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pic);
                    fos.write(buffer);  
                    fos.flush();
                    fos.close();    
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    System.out.println("Exception writing");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a recurring problem I see over and over.  You have no guarantees that the underlying socket will not flush when you don't want it to.  If it does, then the client can get a partial Object, and ObjectInputStream will throw an Exception.

The way to deal with it is to have the server write the Object to an intermediate byte[] via a ByteArrayOutputStream.  You then send a simple header describing the length of the bytes to follow, followed by the contents of the byte[] (flushing after each write).  On the client side, you do the reverse of this:  read the simple header so you know how many bytes to expect, then read into a byte[] via a ByteArrayInputStream, and from there you can read into a ObjectInputStream.  Of course, since you're just writing to a file anyway, you could skip the ObjectInputStream on the client side and just directly write the byte[] to a file.

```
import java.io.*;

public class junk extends ClassLoader {


  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new junk();
  }

  public void marshal(OutputStream socketOutputStream, Object obj) 
    throws Exception 
  {

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

    oos.writeObject(obj);

    byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();

    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socketOutputStream);

    // header
    dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
    dos.flush();

    dos.write(bytes);
    dos.flush();
  }

  public Object unmarshal(InputStream socketInputStream) throws Exception {

    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socketInputStream);

    int numToRead = dis.readInt();

    byte[] bytes = new byte[numToRead];

    dis.readFully(bytes);

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);

    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);

    return ois.readObject();

  }

}
```

Comment: And on the client reading side you also need to cater for split packets so you need to keep reading until you've read numToRead bytes.

Comment: @user726092 I have tried that but with small change to create a file but it is not working.Here is the clients side ` DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());int numToRead = dis.readInt();byte[] bytes =  new byte[numToRead];dis.readFully(bytes);ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);ois.readObject();String pic="copy"+studId+".pdf";System.out.println(pic);FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pic);fos.write(bytes); fos.flush();fos.close();`

Comment: And the Server-side `out.println("AcceptFile,");
   ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
      oos.writeObject((Object)fn);
  
      byte[] bytes = bos.toByteArray();
  
      DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
  
      // header
      dos.writeInt(bytes.length);
      dos.flush();
  
      dos.write(bytes);
      dos.flush();`